# Spring integration jdbc oubound gateway select query returning only one record

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to fetch records from database using spring integration jdbc outbound gateway. I have lot of records in database but the following code is returning only one record in the payload.

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway
query="select * from payee"
request-channel="input"
reply-channel="output"
data-source="dataSource"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `max-rows-per-poll="0"`:

```
   <xsd:attribute name="max-rows-per-poll" type="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:documentation>
                            When using a select query, you can set a
                            custom limit regarding the number of rows
                            extracted. Otherwise by default only the first
                            row will be extracted into the outgoing message.

                            If set to '0' all rows are extracted.
                        </xsd:documentation>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:attribute>
```